# Toilet fill valve drips slightly when turning back on

Tags: toilet

I turned the fill valve on my loo off to unclog the toilet and as I go to turn clockwise to turn back on it drips slightly so bit worried to turn on in case I find myself with a big leak!!!:(
First home owner and just wondering if this is normal before I do turn back on.
TIA

Comment: Can you take a picture of the valve?

Comment: Is there a nut behind the valve handle?  If so, tighten it a bit.  Usually clockwise shuts off a valve.

Comment: don't you mean `fill valve`?

Comment: "turn clockwise to turn back on", don't you mean anti-clockwise (counter-clockwise in US)? Stop valves turn clockwise to shut off...

Comment: Is this valve the fill valve on the inside of the toilet, or is this the supply valve that supplies water to the toilet?

Answer (score 1):

If this is the old (cheap) oval-handle shut-off valve behind the toilet, many have parts that deteriorate over time.  In your situation I would:

- Go ahead and try to open it all the way up (but with something to catch drips nearby).  It is common for these old valves to drip while turning and in mid-position, but be leak-free when all the way open or closed.
- Plan to replace the valve or the valve components.  I've had several that just seemed to disintegrate when I closed them for the first time in years.  The next time you need to work on the toilet, the valve may not shut off.  When planning for it, this is an easy job.  When it breaks late Saturday afternoon because you're doing something to the toilet, it's super annoying.

Answer (score 0):

I am with jack here a photo of the leak or a description would be helpful,

at the shutoff valve not the fill valve on the “crapper” itself.
 A leaky shutoff valve the valve stem packing may need a slight tightening, the nut below the handle, give it a 1/4 turn clockwise and see if the drip stops, this is common with older valves. Sometimes the valves need repacking but many times just tighten the packing nut will seal things up and last for years.